# Typescript, how to get rid of these switch statements

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Typescript basic question;

`loadedExercise.exercise` contains an exercise that has been loaded from an API. After the load, I apply some computations to that loaded exercise and I leave them inside `translationsAudiosOthers`. Then I create a number of fields containing statistics that are different for each type of exercise. `visitedBranch` is a formal parameter that a function containing the mentioned switch statement receives, which indicates the specific statistic field of that exercise that I want to retrieve so I can show it in a react UI

Given a switch/case like this, how would you improve it? I don't want to maintain it in case I add more exercise types and I'm 100% sure there must be a better way of doing this using generics or similar

```js
switch (loadedExercise.exercise.type) {
      case ExerciseTypes.typeA:
        return (loadedExercise.exercise.translationsAudiosOthers as TypeAExerciseLocalizations)[
          visitedBranch as TypeAStatBranches
        ];

      case ExerciseTypes.typeB:
        return (loadedExercise.exercise
          .translationsAudiosOthers as TypeBExerciseLocalizations)[
          visitedBranch as TypeBStatBranches
        ];

      case ExerciseTypes.TypeN:
        return (loadedExercise.exercise
          .translationsAudiosOthers as TypeNExerciseLocalizations)[
          visitedBranch as TypeNStatBranches
        ];
    }
```

Please note I am trying to avoid using `any` as in

```js
return (loadedExercise.exercise.translationsAudiosOthers as any)[
          visitedBranch as any
        ];
```

as I lose autocomplete and I know we must avoid using `any` everytime we can.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using an interface but based on this code that's a guess. At best this is lacking detail, at worst it's opinion based and should be closed

Comment: It's hard to say *how* to improve it without having more context here. What is `loadedExcercise.excercise`? What is `visitedBranch`? What types are at play here? Can you change them? What is actually happening in the code?

Comment: Also, note that the type assertions *right now* aren't that much different to using `as any`. Slightly better but ultimately serve the same purpose. There is no actual type safety provided, you're just overruling the compiler in either case.

Comment: Apologies for not being enough specific! `loadedExercise.exercise` contains an exercise that has been loaded from an API. After the load, I apply some computations to that loaded exercise and I leave them inside `translationsAudiosOthers ` Then I create a number of fields containing statistics that are different for each type of exercise. `visitedBranch` is a formal parameter that a function containing the mentioned `switch` statement receives, which indicates the specific statistic field of that exercise that I want to retrieve so I can show it in a react UI.

Comment: There's still information that is required before a specific answer can be written. The parameter type of `loadedExercise` is key as well as the signature of the enclosing function.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to create a interface to map out the types you want(assuming ExerciseTypes is a enum):

```js
interface ExerciseTypeToLocalizations {
    [ExerciseTypes.typeA]: TypeAExerciseLocalizations;
    [ExerciseTypes.typeB]: TypeBExerciseLocalizations;
    [ExerciseTypes.typeN]: TypeNExerciseLocalizations;
}
interface ExerciseTypeToStatBranches {
    [ExerciseTypes.typeA]: TypeAStatBranches;
    [ExerciseTypes.typeB]: TypeBStatBranches;
    [ExerciseTypes.typeN]: TypeNStatBranches;
}

// instead of a switch statement
return (
    loadedExercise.exercise.translationsAudiosOthers 
    as ExerciseTypeToLocalizations[typeof loadedExercise.exercise.type]
)[visitedBranch as ExerciseTypeToStatBranches[typeof loadedExercise.exercise.type]]
```

With what was presented, this is the best I can do. If you can provide more context to the code I'm sure there is a more elegant way using generics.